# Send mail with JavaMail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have the next problem sending an email with Java and I don't know why. Doing a debug I get this and I don't know why. The trace to follow the mistake is this:

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.4.5
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax
.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsyste
ms, Inc], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com
.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLSt
ore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsyst
ems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.su
n.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=jav
ax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc],
com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP
3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.
sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STOR
E,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtps=javax.mail.Prov
ider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc],
pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems
, Inc], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun
Microsystems, Inc], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.S
MTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map

DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.s
mtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth false
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.businesscloud.es", port 465, isSSL f
alse
```

The code to do this it's this, just it's a simple function where I do this:

```
String[] lista_envio = enviar_a.split(";");

        String smtpHost = "smtp.businesscloud.es";
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host",smtpHost);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", 465);  
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", "");
        props.put("mail.smtp.password","");
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        Session sesion = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,null);

        Message correo = new MimeMessage(sesion);

        correo.setSubject(asunto.trim().toUpperCase());

        correo.setFrom(new InternetAddress(enviado_por));

        for (int i = 0; i < lista_envio.length; i++)
        {
           System.out.println("Dentro del for de enviar_correos");
            correo.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(lista_envio[i]));
        }

        correo.setText(cuerpo);
        correo.addHeader("X-Priority", "3");





        System.out.println("Voy a mandar el mail");
        Transport.send(correo);
```

The exception I have after sending is: Unknown SMTP host: smtp.businesscloud.es, It is weird.

What I'm doing wrong?. Thanks so much

Comment: Does your smtp gateway allow anonymous mail sending? That is perfect candidate for becoming a spam hub. You should show us the Exception that gives you after Transport.send(). I bet it is related with authentication (you provided no user or password)

Comment: The exception after sending message is: Unknown SMTP host: smtp.businesscloud.es, It is weird.

Comment: are you sure the address is correct? Can you access / ping it?

Comment: 1) Are you sure your host is valid? Traceroute and ping to it fails. 2) Port 465 is normally used for secure email, which means you will need to use an SSL connection

Comment: The JavaMail FAQ has [debugging tips](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).

Comment: Host smtp.businesscloud.es not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)